# Vector inner product in terms of norms using fundamental theorem of optimization

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, convex-optimization, inner-products

I read [here](https://ee227c.github.io/notes/ee227c-notes.pdf) under Lipschitz functions section that using the fundamental theorem of optimization, the vector inner product of $u$ and $v$ can be written like this:

$$\langle u, v\rangle \;= \frac{1}{2} (||u||^2 + ||v||^2 - ||u-v||^2)$$

The only property I know that lets me write dot product in terms of norms is the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality but that looks vastly different. Can someone explain this property to me and maybe show it's proof? I don't want to blindly apply it in my sum. And I could not find a proof for it anywhere else.

Comment: This comes from the fact that $\|u-v\|^2=\langle u-v, u-v\rangle$. Just expand the left-hand side and you'll get the result.

Comment: This is a [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) ((2) in the Other forms for real vector spaces section), derived from the parallelogram law.

Comment: Thanks @EricTowers

Comment: Thanks @StefanLafon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @StefanLafon notes, for a vector space over $\Bbb R$ we get$$\Vert u-v\Vert^2=\langle u-v,\,u-v\rangle=\langle u,\,u\rangle-\langle u,\,v\rangle-\langle v,\,u\rangle+\langle v,\,v\rangle=\Vert u\Vert^2-2\langle u,\,v\rangle+\Vert v\Vert^2.$$Now rearrange. Complex spaces require [something different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#For_vector_spaces_with_complex_scalars), because $\langle v,\,u\rangle=\langle u,\,v\rangle^\ast$ differs from $\langle u,\,v\rangle$ in general.

Comment: Thanks can you please show me how to rearrange? We have an extra $\langle u, v\rangle$ on the right, and If we take it to the left then won't it just remain hanging?

Comment: @ParthTamane I suggest you try again: if you make $2\langle u,\,v\rangle$ the subject, then you just need to halve.

Comment: Nevermind got it. Sorry about this. New notations are confusing. :D

Comment: And the expansion you did for $\langle u - v, u - v\rangle$ works the same as it would for scalar product of *(x -y)(x-y)*, correct?

Comment: @ParthTamane Yes, "works the same" in the sense that $\langle a,\,b\rangle$ on vectors, like $cd$ on scalars, is [bilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map), which lets us [do what'd you'd expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOIL_method). (Inner products on complex spaces, however, are [sesquilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) instead.)

Comment: Thanks. :) I love how you stated it mathematically. :D And I don't even want to think about complex spaces, ML math is complex enough without including complex numbers.